# How can I keep SQL Server 2012 Management Studio connected to the DB for longer periods of time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Got a question on SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

Is there a way to set up/customize the Management Studio so that if I don't use it for 30 minutes (approximately) it won't boot me out of the application and make me sign in all over again?

I don't want to keep it on forever, but an extra 30 minutes/1 hour would be nice. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I never had problem with this before but after our company changed the network connection provider my query windows get disconnected every now and then. Object explorer window stays connected OK in my case.

Comment: i usually leave SSMS open when going out for lunch; after 1 hr away from the pc the connection to sql server are still open and working, both object explorer and query windows. are you sure there is no physical disconnection while away? maybe powersaving eth card or something like that?

Comment: No I'm pretty sure there isn't a physical disconnection, at least none that I'm aware of, I walk away - my comp goes into sleep mode, come back, and then I got to log back into all the open sql windows >.<

Comment: And if you disable sleep mode on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_who or sp_who2 to see what your SPID is while connected. If your management studio is connected you will show up as a user in the list. If something is killing your connection it is either your client configuration at connection time (connection timeout) or something configured to kill connections at the server (Group Policy on the network). By default your connection just goes into "Sleeping" status if no client connection timeout is issued at the time of connection. Connections don't typically get killed because it affects caching session for that spid to just drop it.

Comment: What group policy can do that? I would rather guess it is some router settings or something like that. But really do not understand how running `sp_who` could help me.

Comment: I agree. It would be something bizarre somebody implemented to kill connections. Knowing your spid helps you to see what is going on with your process and if it is sleeping. You could track what is going on with it by that ID. For example, you can see if it is sleeping, killed or even track how long it takes for it to "dissapear" from the sp_who results.